# Bounce a pin in google maps lower and faster

Tags: google-maps, bounce

is there any possibility to make a pin to bounce lower and faster?
i want pin to jump just a little and more often.
i tried by css but it doesnt work. can i just edit api bouncing? like duration or speed?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
                if (this.getAnimation() == null || typeof this.getAnimation() === 'undefined') {
                    clearTimeout(bounceTimer);

                    var that = this;

                    bounceTimer = setTimeout(function(){
                         that.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
                    },
                    100);

                }
               //$('.gmnoprint img').addClass('anim');

            });
```